# VBA issues understanding

Tags: vba, excel

I was asked to **continu** a code on **VBA** Excel on the following code :

```
Sub Ajout_45()
   Ajout (45)
End Sub

Sub Ajout_60()
  Ajout (60)
End Sub

Sub Ajout(diametre)
Dim nomforme As String
Dim basenom As String
basenom = "Forme_"

If (diametre = 45) Then
nomforme = basenom + "45"
ElseIf (diametre = 60) Then
nomforme = basenom + "60"
End If

ActiveSheet.Shapes(nomforme).Copy
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 204, 153)
Selection.ShapeRange.Name = compt
compt = compt + 1
Selection.OnAction = "Etat"

End Sub
```

This is my first time using VBA so I'm trying to understand the code.
What I understand basically is it creates a shape based on a shape already existing. It copy and paste it. Then fill the new shape color with RGB given. Then give a name to the new shape. Then call on click the macro Etat.
If I miss something or I am wrong somewhere please let me know.

My second question is why if comment the line `Selection.OnAction = "Etat"` every new shape created keep as macro creating new shape.

Many thanks in advance for any helpers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Shape.OnAction` Property is the name of the Macro that is called when you Click on the button.

So, this macro creates a new shape, colours it in, and tells it "When someone clicks on you, run the macro `Etat`"

I would, however, recommend you [try to avoid using `Select` in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1).  Using `Shape.Duplicate` and a `With` constructor will be tidier and safer:

```
Sub Ajout(diameter AS Long)
    Dim nomforme As String
    Dim basenom As String
    basenom = "Forme_"

    If (diametre = 45) Then
        nomforme = basenom + "45"
    ElseIf (diametre = 60) Then
        nomforme = basenom + "60"
    End If

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(nomforme).Duplicate 'Duplicate Shape
        .Name = compt 'Set Name
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 204, 153) 'Set Colour
        .OnAction = "Etat" 'Set the "click" macro
        compt = compt + 1 'Increase counter
    End With
End Sub
```

(Using `ActiveSheet` can also cause issues - if you always use this on a specific worksheet, try referencing that directly, e.g. `Sheet1.Shapes` instead of `ActiveSheet.Shapes`)

Comment: Thank you for your swift anwser. Indeed it is cleaner to avoid select and ActiveSheet. However I don't understand when delete the call of the macro Etat it keeps duplicating a shape whenever I click on a shape. I feel like its an infinite loop.... I don't undestand the process behind this

Comment: @Lyess2b The only thing I can assume there is that the Shape you are copying *already* has a Macro assigned to it, which is to create a new shape - so, the copy has this Macro assigned to.  To remove it, set `OnAction = ""`

Comment: I see, once a macro is assigned to a shape it sticks to it for ever ?

Comment: Also how is named the new shape created ?

Comment: @Lyess2b Until replaced or removed, yes.  The new shape created is being given a number as a name - whatever number is stored in `compt` at that time.  (`.Name = compt`)

Comment: I see, thank you. By the way I want to test if this new shapes are within a range of cells. I want to use Intersect but in a If I can't write the syntax correctly. However thank you for the explanations!

Comment: All shapes are held within rectangular bounding-boxes (even circles).  The cell that the top-left corner of this box overlaps is `Shape.TopLeftCell` - the cell at the bottom-right corner is `Shape.BottomRightCell`.  This means that the range of cells that a non-rotated shape overlaps is `Range(Shape.TopLeftCell, Shape.BottomRightCell)` - to check if it intersects `RangeToCheck` you would use something like `If Not (Intersect(RangeToCeheck, Range(Shape.TopLeftCell, Shape.BottomRightCell)) Is Nothing) Then`